# Q : Python time

Tags: python, python-2.7, time

I would like to use ·time()· to launch an event. An example would be to `print("test")` for 3 seconds. For that I did this:

```
from time import time, sleep

from random import random

t = time()
n = 3

print(n, time() - t)

for i in range(100):
    sleep(0.04)
    print(time() - t)
    if time() - t > n:
        print("test")
        break
```

and it works! But in my game, in a while loop, it does not work... Why not?

Comment: What do you mean by "launch a print("test") all the 3 seconds"? I know you said English isn't your first language but do you think you could try and be more specific?

Comment: We're missing quite a bit of context here - are you using an event loop elsewhere for "your game" ?

Comment: I'm afraid that since you've shown an example that works as desired, we can't really help you with the issue you're having with your game loop, since we don't know what that issue is. Please give an example that shows the same issue (you may need to use the same game loop in the example code)!

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, it seems you don't know how to run a simple gameloop and run some test code after 3 seconds, here's some naive approach:

```
from time import time, sleep

from random import random

start_time = time()
n = 3

while True:
    elapsed_time = time() - start_time
    sleep(0.04)
    print(elapsed_time)
    if elapsed_time > n:
        print("test")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to achieve something else during the 3 second delay period, rather than just going round a while loop, try using a time-delayed thread. For example, the following

```
import threading
import time

def afterThreeSec():
    print("test")
    return

t1 = threading.Timer(3, afterThreeSec)
t1.setName('t1')
t1.start()

print ("main")
time.sleep(1)
print ("main")
time.sleep(1)
print ("main")
time.sleep(1)
print ("main")
time.sleep(1)
print ("main")
```

gives the output:

```
main
main
main
test
main
main
```